# Pentaho - charts not displaying in CDE dashboards

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

I installed Pentaho 5.3 community version on Windows.
My problem is that when displaying a CDE dashboard, text is displaying just fine but charts do not display at all.
I got this issue with both sample CDE dashboard and my own dashboards.

I see nothing into pentago log that could explain that problem.
I gotr the problem with both Firefox and Chrom latest versions.

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: do you have any javascript errors in the browser's console? You may want to upgrade your ctools plugins, they just released a new version today.

Comment: Thanks, just solved my problem by reinstalling both latest java 7 jdk and latest pentaho version !