# Pentaho CDE new charts not rendering

Tags: render, display, pentaho-cde

New charts I add to an existing CDE dashboard are not rendering.  Existing charts are working ok.

I have also created brand new dashboards and the same problem occurred.

I checked [Pentaho - charts not displaying in CDE dashboards](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28880879/6061977) and [Pentaho CDE Bar chart display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35169865/pentaho-cde-bar-chart-display).  I am not in a position to reinstall everything as this is a live system.  However, I tried it on a backup installation and the same problem occurred.  I also checked the height and width as suggested in the second posting and they are ok.

Using the developer tools on the rendered objects I see the following (sorry in advance for using screenshots):

[The working pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZZs5.jpg)
[The non-working pie chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dwKJ.jpg)

Both pie charts are accessing the same query so they should be the same.

I hope someone can help.

Thanks,
Fergus